# Label text messed up with Pure CSS select

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, pure-css

[PLNKR example of problem](https://plnkr.co/edit/ggG0prrNfOFipTFINADX?p=preview)

The label reads Group By, but the letters are all superimposed for some reason.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Label font</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pure/0.6.0/pure.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//builder.yaas.io/public/js/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="UICtrl">

    <form class="pure-form pure-form-aligned">
      <fieldset>

        <div class="pure-g">
          <div class="pure-u-md-1">
            <label for="graphType">Group By: </label>
            <select id="graphType" class="pure-input-1">
              <option disabled selected value> -- Select a Graph Type --</option>
              <option> Graph type 1 </option>
            </select>

          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The problem goes away if I don't use the Pure CSS library. Is there anyway I can have the label font without messing up while keeping the Pure CSS?

Comment: `letter-spacing: -0.31em;` in pure.css see https://plnkr.co/edit/ZHFiu3HrNU37IC5rbZzi?p=preview

Comment: I don't have experience in Pure CSS library .However I can write another stylesheet overriding some of the rules so the problem goes away. Is it okay for you?

Comment: That'd be fine @geeksal

Comment: @NishantRoy you have the answer now...

Comment: Yes, my bad I didn't see @Satpal's post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize your label css

```
label {
   letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
```